# Remove CRLF from middle of a line with CSV module

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm reading some data from an Excel file and writing in a CSV file. However, there are some CRLF in the middle of the text and it's causing me issues. How do I go about removing them and just keeping the line endings at the end of each line?

```
import xlrd
import csv

with xlrd.open_workbook("test.xls") as wb:
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)  
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:   
        c = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
        for r in range(sh.nrows):
           c.writerow(sh.row_values(r))
```

The line in the spreadsheet is like this:

```
Saks Fifth Avenue: 
40; International: 6; OFF 5TH:
```

However, I want to remove the CRLF:

```
Saks Fifth Avenue: 40; International: 6; OFF 5TH:
```

Comment: Could you post a representative snippet from your input file that makes it possible to run the code to diagnose the problem? Thank you!

Comment: It would be something like this where the user has entered a CRLF in the middle of the string

    Saks Fifth Avenue: 
    40; International: 6; OFF 5TH: 

Want it to be like this:
    Saks Fifth Avenue: 40; International: 6; OFF 5TH: